# Why legend and ylabel cover axis ticks even using tight layout?

Tags: python, plot

I created a chart using plt.tight_layout but label and legend cover my axis. Why?

```
fig7 = plt.figure(figsize=(19/2.54,10/2.54))
ax1 = fig7.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.scatter(S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] !='DHW', 'Date'],S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] !='DHW', 'eta daily (PCS)'], color='k',s=9, label='\u03B7_day (SH & DHW)')
ax1.scatter(S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] =='DHW', 'Date'],S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] =='DHW', 'eta daily (PCS)'], facecolors='none', edgecolors='k',s=11, label='\u03B7_day (Only DHW)')
ax1.set_ylabel('\u03B7_day (-)')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.scatter(S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] !='DHW', 'Date'],S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] !='DHW', 'Qmean gas allday(kW)'], marker='^', color='r',s=9, label='Qgas_day (SH & DHW)')
ax2.scatter(S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] =='DHW', 'Date'],S1_daily.loc[S1_daily['Work Type'] =='DHW', 'Qmean gas allday(kW)'], marker='^', facecolors='none', edgecolors='r',s=11, label='Qgas_day (Only DHW)')
plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(right=1.08)
ax2.set_ylabel('Qgas_day (kW)', rotation=270)
fig7.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.007),ncol=2, fontsize=7)
plt.tight_layout()
```

here you find my actual situation:
https://docdro.id/asLjp4D

Comment: Hi I'm not sure to understand you the right way, this is the normal behavior => Your legend is "attached" to the coordinates you gave to it and is stil in the frame of the figue. So the tight_layout won't change anything. Would you explain us the expected output you're trying to reach ?

"tight_layout automatically adjusts subplot params so that the subplot(s) fits in to the figure area. This is an experimental feature and may not work for some cases. It only checks the extents of ticklabels, axis labels, and titles."

 [https://matplotlib.org/users/tight_layout_guide.html]

Comment: Ok i understand what you say about the legend, and what regards the second ylabel? I mean 'Qgas_day (kW)' should not cover the values of y axis, but it does and i don't know how to move it, i tried again with bbox_to_anchor but it doesn't work